# Find the line passing thought the point $p=(1,2,0)$, paralel to the plane...

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, affine-geometry

Find the line passing thought the point $p=(1,2,0)$, paralel to the plane $P=\{x,y,z \mid x+2y-z=-4\}$ and crossing the line $L=\{(x,y,z):x+2y=2, y+z=4\}$

So I've tried to put the equation of plane and insert the point, because I think that if line is paralel to the plane, then line is contained in the plane.

But I've checked, that the point don't lay in the plane, because

$x+2y-z=1+4-0=5 \neq -4$

So I'm stuck here.

-- EDIT --

Is that correct:

$x+2y-z=k\,\,\, k\in\mathbb{R}$

Intercepting point
$
\begin{cases}
x+2y=z\\
x+2y=2\\
x+z=4
\end{cases}\implies\begin{cases}
z=2\\
x=2\\
y=0
\end{cases}$

General line equation

$p_{1}-\lambda p_{2}=0 $

$(1-2\lambda,\,\,2,\,\,\,-2\lambda)$

$
x=1-2\lambda$

$y=2$

$z=-2\lambda$

So the answer is

$x=1-z$

$y=2$

Comment: You find it.${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Please have a *thorough* look at the [FAQ about homework questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question).

Comment: OK, I'll look now

Comment: @AlexanderGruber Fixed. I don't know how to find it

Answer (score 2):

It says that the line you need to find is *parallel* to the given plane, not that it's *on* that plane.

As this is a homework problem, I'm not going to do it for you, but I will say that you've already done one step, although you may not have realised it.

There are three steps - find plane, find intercept point, construct line through points. I'll leave it to you to figure out what I'm saying from there.

Comment: How to find intercept points? I need to solve equation system with the $x+y2-z=k$ and equations for line $L$ ?

Comment: This point will be (2,0,2) ?

Comment: You need to find the plane first. You haven't done that, yet.

Comment: If at any point you think you've solved it, check if it satisfies the three conditions - does it pass through the appropriate point? Does it have an intercept with the given line? Is it parallel to the given plane?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The possible directions of your line are given by the equation
$$
x+2y-z=0
$$

---

Your solution isn't correct: it is true that $(1,2,0)$ is on your line, but the intersection with $L$ is empty:
$$
\begin{cases}
2+z=4\\
(1-z)+4=2
\end{cases}
$$
gives $z=2$ (first equation) and $z=3$ (second equation.

---

Here is one possible solution, using Cartesian equations, like yours (my hint would have provided a solution in parametric equations).

What we're going to do is find the required line as the intersection of two planes: one parallel to the given one and the other containing $L$, both passing through $P=(1,2,0)$.

For the first plane we just have to put $(1,2,0)$ in the equation $x+2y-z=k$, giving
$$
\pi_1: x+2y-z=5
$$
Now, the pencil of planes containing $L$ is simply
$$
\mathcal{F}: \lambda(x+2y-2)+\mu(y+z-4)=0
$$
thus to find the plane through $P\notin L$ we just need to substitute $(1,2,0)$
$$
\begin{gather}
\lambda(1+4-2)+\mu(2-4)=3\lambda-2\mu=0\\
3\lambda=2\mu
\end{gather}
$$
therefore our second plane is given by
$$
\pi_2:2(x+2y-2)+3(y+z-4)=2x+7y+3z-16=0
$$
hence the required line is given by
$$
R:\left\{(x,y,z):x+2y-z=5, 2x+7y+3z=16\right\}
$$
You can now check that $R\cap L\neq\varnothing$ and that $P\in R$.

Comment: So every paralel plane is described by $x+2y-z=0$?

Comment: No, every parallel plane is described by $x+2y-z=k$ with $k\in \Bbb R$ (same orthogonal direction, but passing through different points). If you are taking values in $\Bbb R$, of course.

Comment: Thanks. Could You check if I've done it correctly, in question edit?

Comment: I'm sorry but no, it isn't.

Comment: I provided a full solution in my edit.